# Streams of data with only Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, kotlinx.coroutines

With RxJava Ive become accustomed to my repositories returning Observables of data which automatically update whenever theres an underlying change. I acheive this by simply having a subject in my repository that gets notified with the relevant change info, and observables like `getAll()` go off of that.

As an example, take this psuedo code like snippet:

```
fun getAll(): Observable<List<Model> {
    subject
        .filter { isChangeRelevant(it) }
        .startWith(initialChangeEvent)
        .map { queryAll() }
}
```

---

**Ive been curious about how and if the same thing can be acheived using coroutines only?**

Comment: See https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/reactive/coroutines-guide-reactive.md.

Comment: Your example is a simple matter for any streams implementation to handle, including basic Java Streams, Java Reactive Streams or co-routines. As such, it does not exemplify merging observable chains, divergent chains, feedback chains or cross-thread communication, which are the bread-and-butter of the RxJava world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Kotlin Coroutines `Channel`s.

If you only want your values to be emitted like a stream (so you can `for-each` off of it) you can use `produce` to create them (which returns a `ReceiveChannel`):

```
fun test(): ReceiveChannel<Int>{
        return produce {
            send(1)
            send(5)
            send(100)
        }
    }
```

You can use a for-each (or `consumeEach`) on the values of `test()` to receive its values.

If you want your channel to be exactly like RxJava's PublishSubject, you can use ConflatedBroadCastChannel,  and emit values to it:

```
val broadCastChannel = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<Int>()
```

You can use `broadCastChannel.offer(value)` to send values to the channel.

To receive values from the channel you can use a simple for-each loop:

```
for (i in broadCastChannel.openSubscription()) {
       //your values
}
```